# CSS - positioning icon inside a button

Tags: css

I'm trying to add an icon inside a button. The problem is that whenever I add the icon, it changes the shape of the button (it makes it taller, and sometimes wider depending on how big the icon is), and it mis-aligns the text of the button so that it is no longer centered, rather the text has been pushed down.

```
 <button>
   <i class="material-icons">weekend</i>
   Test
 </button>
```

And the CSS:

```
i {
    color: #669FAB;
    font-size: 24px !important;
 }

 button {
    min-width: 100px;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uxs71ymz/1/

I would like the icon to shift to the left, while having the text remain centered inside the button.

Comment: try adding "  vertical-align:middle;" property to i.material-icons

Comment: You should consider using a Div instead of a button, you can get the same functionality from it and they are generally are more equivalent across different browsers.

Comment: @TylerGaffaney Where do you get that `<button>` and `<div>` have "same functionality"?

Comment: @Rob I said they _can_ have the same functionality.  `<div onclick="yourFunction()"></div>` is now a div that can be clicked and customized like a `<button>`.  Good question Rob.

Comment: @TylerGaffaney Well, then we'd be arguing semantics but I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @Rob Sweet thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hi here is the css code

CSS

```
i {
  color: #669FAB;
  font-size: 24px !important;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

button {
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/hq9t8rk4/

```
button i.material-icons {
  color: #669FAB;
  font-size: 24px;
  // Add the below
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

button {
  min-width: 100px;
  // Add the below
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px 50px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
```